# Validate the user's input of only 0's and 1's

Tags: python-3.x

I have to convert an 8-bit binary number to a decimal number. I believe that I have the conversion correct along with validating if the user inputted an 8-bit binary number (no more, no less) but I am stuck on validating the user's input for only 0's and 1's.

Any help would be great. I feel like I am overthinking this but I tried everything.

Here is the code I have:

```
while True:
binary = input("Please enter a 8-bit binary number: ")
if len(binary) < 8 or len(binary) > 8:
    print("Must be an 8 bit binary!")

else:
    print(int(binary, 2))
    break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, first thing first, you use this line:

```
if len(binary) < 8 or len(binary) > 8:
```

it is way more readable to just say:

```
if len(binary) != 8
```

Now this is how I would implement your code:

```
while True:
    binary = input("Please enter a 8-bit binary number: ")

    for item in binary:
        if item not in {'0','1'}:
            print("Must only contains 0's and 1's !")
            break

    if len(binary) != 8:
        print("Must be an 8 bit binary!")

    else:
        print(int(binary, 2))
        break
```

Note that this will check for both validations you expected while providing a relevant insight to the user depending on his particular mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You're checking the length, but not validating the users input. eg,

s = '12345678' is a valid input into your code.

If you really want to validate, you could do something simple like

```
s1 = '11010101111'

if s1.count('1') + s1.count('0') == len(s1):
    print(int(s1,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're a fan of regexes:

```
import re
s1='10010011'
print(re.match(r'[10]{8}', s1) is None)
```

This will match `10010011`, but not `110010100` or `12345689` or `12345678`.